# Accesing the parameters via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am submitting a form via ajaxsubmit plugin of jQuery,Which  issues a url back to my page with few parameters in the query string.The problem is that i cant get those parameters in php or on success event of ajax submit.is there any way to get those parameters?
You can see it here http://videoproduction-pro.com/video/ open the firebug's net panel and it is in the 4th request the uploads.gdata.youtube.com one.The form im submitting has an action with external URL in it.

Any body knows what the issue here is?.

Regards
Himanshu Sharma

Comment: Can you not get the url parameters client side (javascript) or server side (php). It sounds like the latter, but you ask us to look at client side code?

Comment: Thanx for your attention mrtsherman,The form im submitting using ajax is for an external URL which actually redirects back to my page with params in query string and i cant get those params at all

Comment: You still haven't answered the question. Do you want them client side (javascript) or server side (php)?

Comment: Its good if i get them server side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them client side then you can use gup.

```
//for http://www.example.com?frank=value
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}

// = 'value'
var frank_param = gup( 'frank' );
```

If you want them server side then use the [get global](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

```
$_GET['frank']
```